# Can't make nested components

Tags: blazor

Sorry, if the question is related to my lack of experience. I am trying to make a component library for working with a mapbox from blazor. Now I have a main component MapBoxView, that displays a map and MapboxGeocoder, which used for finding objects . Each of component has a procedure in the main component OnFirstAfterRenderAsync():

```
protected async override Task OnFirstAfterRenderAsync()
{
    await base.OnFirstAfterRenderAsync();
    Dictionary<string, object> o = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ...
    await JsInvokeAsync<object>("mapgl.mymap.initMap", o);
}
```

and in nested component:

```
protected async override Task OnFirstAfterRenderAsync()
{
    await base.OnFirstAfterRenderAsync();
    Dictionary<string, object> o = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    o.Add("container", container);
    await JsInvokeAsync<object>("mapgl.mygeocoder.initGeocoder", o);
}
```

When in demo program I use code:

```
@page "/"

<MapBoxView zoom=@_zoom container=@containerName mapCenter=@centerOfView>
</MapBoxView>

<MapBoxGeocoder Id="geocoder">
</MapBoxGeocoder>
```

then all works fine, and I get the picture I want:[image]

When in demo program I use code:

```
<MapBoxView zoom=@_zoom container=@containerName mapCenter=@centerOfView>
    <MapBoxGeocoder Id="geocoder">
    </MapBoxGeocoder>
</MapBoxView>
```

That is, I put the nested component in the main one, then the geocoder (left bottom window with text - Search on the picture) is not shown and the program does not enter the procedure OnFirstAfterRenderAsync() of MapBoxGeocoder component.
Main component MapBoxView has razor code:

```
@namespace MapBoxBlazor

@inherits BaseMapBoxView

    <div id='mapContainer'>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the docs about [ChildContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#child-content).

You need to use a `RenderFragment` named `ChildContent` to allow you to render nested components.

The parent component must have the property

```
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

And render it in the place your want. e.g.

```
<div> 
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

And this property will render everything inside the parent component.

So for you case, `MapBoxView` should have the `ChildContent` and render it inside for it to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know this way. The question was, maybe there is a way to deal as with "div" - inside which it is possible to insert arbitrary other tags . Although if I know how the html tags are implemented, then it seems obvious that this is not possible. It would be comfortable to place other tags inside the map (geocoder and so on) tag without affecting the map tag